# how to call child componenet on button click in parent componenet in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vue-router

Inside parent component I include child component, I want to render(trigger) the child component when click on button. here is my code

```
<script>
    import childComponenet'../../components/child-component.vue';

    export default {
        name:'parentComponenet',
        components:{
            childComponenet
        },
methods: {
            goToChild(tag){
              //go to child component
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Obviously missing a lot of your code here.  If you just want to render the child when you click a button in the parent, then add a 'v-if' directive to the child in the parent template.  Use the parent button to toggle a boolean that will show/hide the child.  If you want to trigger some logic in the child, you could try passing a prop from the parent to the child that gets updated by the parent when you click the button.  You would also need to set up a watch on the prop in the child.  When the watch is triggered, run logic to do what you want in the child component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $emit or vuex but if it child and parrent use $emit

Answer (score 0):

What do you actually mean? Show the child when the button on the parent is clicked? Or re-render it?

If you want to show/render it, you can do something like

```
<template>
  <button @click="toggleShowChild">Show Child Component</button>
  <ChildComponent v-show="showChild"/>
</template>

<script>
    import childComponenet'../../components/child-component.vue';

    export default {
        name:'parentComponenet',
        components:{
            childComponenet
        },
        data () {
          return {
            showChild: false
          }
        },
        methods: {
            toggleShowChild() {
              this.showChild = !this.showChild
            },
            goToChild(tag){
              //go to child component
        }
  
</script>
```

This is a step further where you can toggle the child with the button. If you want the button to only show the child, you can just do `@click="showChild = true"` on the button, and not write a method at all.
You can do the same with v-if instead of v-show as well. More on the [difference between v-if and v-show](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show).

Comment: thanks, here the scenario is different, I want to downaload pdf when click on the button. the child component is actually a generic export component. every time i click the print button in parent need to download the pdf. show/hide is not needed in my case. i tried ref.child.method(), but I want more generic and destroy the child once downloaded complete.

Comment: @usercomapny so what you want is to call a method on the child? Your question is not very clear... If you want to call a method on the child you can do `this.children[indexOfWantedChild].method()`
Your comment isn't the clearest as well.